# How to convert a dataframe of factor to numeric?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with all factor values

```
V1 V2 V3
 a  b  c
 c  b  a
 c  b  c
 b  b  a
```

How can I convert all the values in the data frame to a new one with numeric values (a to 1, b to 2, c to 3, etc ...)

Answer (score 12):

I would try:

```
> mydf[] <- as.numeric(factor(as.matrix(mydf)))
> mydf
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  2  3
2  3  2  1
3  3  2  3
4  2  2  1
```

Comment: Could you explain why a simple `apply(mydf, 2, as.numeric)` doesn't work?

Comment: @AlbertMasclans, read the first line of the "details" section for `apply`. `apply` first does `as.matrix` on the `data.frame` (which will convert everything to `character`s). If you then directly use `as.numeric` on a `character` vector, you'll end up with a bunch of `NA` values.

Answer (score 10):

Converting from `factor` to `numeric`gives the integer values.  But, if the `factor` columns have levels specified as `c('b', 'a', 'c', 'd')` or `c('c', 'b', 'a')`, the integer values will be in that order.  Just to avoid that, we can specify the `levels` by calling the `factor` again (safer)

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) 
                as.numeric(factor(x, levels=letters[1:3])))
```

---

If we are using `data.table`, one option would be to use `set`.  It would be more efficient for large datasets.  Converting to `matrix` may pose memory problems.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
for(j in seq_along(df1)){
 set(df1, i=NULL, j=j, 
     value= as.numeric(factor(df1[[j]], levels= letters[1:3])))
 }
```

Comment: I 'm curious: how is df1[] <- ... Differ from df1 <-... I think they lead to the same result in the end but maybe by different paths?

Comment: @atiretoo  It preserves the structure as in the original dataset.

Comment: Aha! Thanks yes in particular df1 will still be a data frame

Answer (score 5):

This approach is similar to Ananda's, but uses `unlist()` instead of `factor(as.matrix())`.  Since all your columns are already factors, `unlist()` will combine them into one factor vector with the appropriate levels.

So let's take a look at what happens when we `unlist()` your data frame.

```
unlist(df, use.names = FALSE)
#  [1] a c c b b b b b c a c a
# Levels: a b c
```

Now we can simply run `as.integer()` (or `c()`) on the above code because the integer values of the factors match your desired mapping.  And so the following will revalue your entire data frame.

```
df[] <- as.integer(unlist(df, use.names = FALSE))
## note that you can also just drop the factor class with c()
## df[] <- c(unlist(df, use.names = FALSE))
df
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  1  2  3
# 2  3  2  1
# 3  3  2  3
# 4  2  2  1
```

**Note:** `use.names = FALSE` is not necessary. However, dropping the names attribute will make this process more efficient than not.

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = "b", class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "c"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```